# SQL Trigger - help with fundamentals

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2000

I rarely write triggers.  I can use help setting up the thing.

```
CREATE TRIGGER audit_tableName
ON dbo.tableNameAudit
AFTER CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE on tableName
AS
BEGIN
  --Get Created,updated,deletes items
  INSERT into dbo.tableNameAudit(columns) VALUES ([allCUDitems])

END
GO
```

How do I get an iterate any CREATED, UPDATED, DELETED items that caused the trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214435%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

the short of it are there are 2 special tables, inserted and deleted, that are accessible in your trigger.  inserted will contain updated rows and inserted rows, while deleted will contain updated rows and deleted rows.

make sure that you understand that for a batch operation a trigger is only fired one time, so be sure to handle the possibility of multiple rows being present in those tables.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu - made a lot of progress.  How can I tell which op triggered the trigger when watching INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE?  From what I read in the documentation, it seems I need to take `inserted` on INSERT and `deleted` on UPDATE/DELETE.  I dont care about the new values in the audit trail for UPDATE.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, you can use the Update function, which takes a column name and tells you whether it has been updated, or you could compare the count of inserted and deleted, if they're the same it is an update, or you could manually select the rows from deleted where the inserted and deleted values dont' match

Answer (score 1):

Triggers have access to two [pseudo tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx): `INSERTED` and `DELETED`. As their name suggests, these pseudo tables will contain all the values added or removed from the table. An update will cause a row in each of the pseudo-tables. The structure of these pseudo-tables is identical with the structure of the table on which the table is declared.

In addition the [`UPDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) function inside a trigger will return TRUE for columns that were updated.

Comment: although i'm pretty sure the information is going to be similar, your link is for sql server 2008 r2, not 2000.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERTED.[COLUMN] OR

```
SELECT [COLUMN] 
FROM INSERTED
```

This on SQL Server.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @user728314 if you highlight code and press `{}` you'll code will be formatted